# Why forked childern processes don't output to terminal?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, fork

This code snippet is taken from Programming Python 4th Edition, it's been slightly modified to accommodate my crazy, silly purposes:

```
#xyz.py
import os 

def child():
    print('Hello from child', os.getpid(), flush=True)
    #os._exit(0)

def parent():
    while True:
        newpid = os.fork()
        if newpid == 0:
            child()
        else:
            print('Hello from parent', os.getpid(), newpid, flush=True)
        if input() == 'q': break

parent()
```

I'm running this in terminal:

```
$ python3 xyz.py
Hello from parent 5708 5709
Hello from child 5709
```

Let's start with the first process. The parent continues executing after `else` and waits for input, `q` to break, anything else to continue.

Going to the forked child processes; Looking at the code, any forked child process calls `child` function. `os_exit` was commented out, it's simply skipped. Thus all children execute `parent` too. For the *first* forked child process, there's output in the terminal screen, but the child will have children as well because it'll continue executing `parent` as a result we get a fork bomb and the terminal screen should be spoiled with:

```
Hello from parent 5708 5709
Hello from child 5709
...
```

I commented `if input() == 'q': break` out and I got the expected results.  Be cautious that doing so crashed my system and I had to hard shutdown my machine before continuing writing this question.

Since `input` is placed after `print` in `parent`, there should be an output and children should continue making children of their own,

How does `input` block forked children from making grandchildren?

Comment: Add a prompt to the `input` command, and you'll see that *both* the parent and the child are blocking on input from the *same* input file (namely, the terminal). What happens next depends a lot on how your OS schedules the processes. Type `q` the first time, and one process exits while the other one gets a `EOFError` on its input. Type anything else, and your program will continue for a while, which each process that gets to run blocking on its next call to `input`.

Comment: @chepner That's exactly what happens. But `os.fork` gets executed before `input` why the OS doesn't fork then?

Comment: It does fork; add `os.getpid()` to the prompt displayed by `input` to see which processes are calling `input` each time.

Comment: @chepner Oww! I just realized that I misunderstood the flow of execution. Now I realized why  and what went wrong . Thank you!